# How do I render components within a state in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm learning react and I'm stuck on how to render the birthdays within my this.state. I figured I would use something like:

```
 {this.state.birthdays}
```

but that doesn't seem to reach each birthday. My getElementByID is equal to a container which exists on my HTML. Any advice/help would be great!

```
    class App extends React.Component {
          constructor(props) {
            super(props);

            this.state = {
              birthdays: {
                'January': [{
                  name: 'Mike',
                  date: '1/14/90'
                }, {
                  name: 'Joe',
                  date: '1/7/92'
                }],

                March: [{
                  name: 'Mary',
                  date: '3/7/88'
                }]
              }
            }
          }

          render() {
            return ( 
              <div>

              </div>
            );
          }
        }
ReactDOM.render(<App />, 
document.getElementById('container'));
```

Comment: You're populating your state object, but you're not doing anything with it in the render function, so no data will be displayed, just <div></div>. How are you trying to display it?

Comment: At the beginning of my post I said I tried using {this.state.birthdays} but it didn't work

Comment: In your div you would do something like `{this.state.birthdays['January'][0].name}` or you could use map to loop through the months and display data that way.

Comment: It didn't work because `this.state.birthdays` returns another object. You're trying to get to the data inside the object, which looks like it's inside an array with more objects.

Comment: Hey Joshua what you said worked! But how exactly would I loop through the state if I don't want to specify the month?

Comment: @JoshuaTerrill is right. You need to iterate over the object and tell React what should be displayed. You should be able to validate with a console.log() statement if you're stuck.

Comment: I'm going to type an answer right now @user6840964

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is untested, but something like this should work. Loop over the month keys using `Object.keys`, then reduce each set of birthdays to a flat array:

```
render() {
    return ( 
      <div>
        {Object.keys(this.state.birthdays).reduce((birthdays, month) => {
            return birthdays.concat(this.state.birthdays[month].map((bday) => {
                return (
                    <p>{bday.name} - {bday.date}</p>
                );
            }));
        }, [])}
      </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
{ Object.keys(this.state.birthdays).map(this.renderBirthdays) }
```

And then above your render function create a function called `renderBirthdays` like this:

```
renderBirthdays: function(key) {
    return (
         <div key={key} index={key} details={this.state.birthdays[key]}>
              {details.name} - {details.date}
         </div>
    )
},
render: function() {
    return (
        <div>{ Object.keys(this.state.birthdays).map(this.renderBirthdays) }</div>
    )
}
```

So you can take advantage of [javascripts map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) which will take your object and key them. Then we're going to pass this key into a function called `renderBirthdays` which will iterate over the item. We need to pass a key and an index into the element, and for ease of use, we can pass a details prop into it equal to the currently selected item it's iterating over. That way we can just use `{details.name}` etc in the element.

Comment: Hey thanks so much! I'm still fixing my code, but should renderBirthdays... be right above render() and the {object.keys...} should be within the return, correct? I just want to make sure I'm doing things correctly because I'm still running into issues even though I'm sure what you've done is right.

Comment: Hey thanks so much! I'm running into unexpected token errors so I just need to hunt down a missing paren or something but thanks for all your help!

Comment: You could run your json through a json linter or json format checker or something. One thing that I saw right off the top was that on January you have single quotes around it, and around March you have none. Just make sure all that stuff is standardized across your object, whichever way you choose to go.

Comment: I'll definitely try that as well. Oh yeah! I caught that :)